# print google maps v3

Tags: printing, google-maps-api-3, window.opener

I am trying to create a button that will print a google map embedded on a webpage

see code:

```
function print(){


var contents = window.opener.document.getElementById("map_canvas"); 
document.write(contents.innerHTML); 
window.print(); 

}
```

this is the div that holds my map

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:800px; height:500px;"></div>
```

and this is the print button

```
<input type="button" value="Print" onclick="print()">
```

When I click the print button I get an error "window.opener is null."
What is the correct code to print the map?

Answer (score 0):

window.opener returns a reference to the window that created the window. No window.opener is needed here since you didn't create any new windows.

Directly use window.document.getElementById.

Try this:

```
function print(){
    var contents = window.document.getElementById("map_canvas"); 
    document.write(contents.innerHTML); 
    window.print(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var content = window.document.getElementById("map-canvas"); // get you map details
var newWindow = window.open(); // open a new window
newWindow.document.write(content.innerHTML); // write the map into the new window
newWindow.print(); // print the new window
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score -1):

Check if DIV that contain map on primary window have div with id="map_canvas"